# If mv is in command, do not ask to correct name of file (in zsh)

Tags: shell, zsh, mv

When using zsh, if I'm renaming a file, the shell sometimes assumes I've made a typo in the filename and suggests another. Is there any way disable this specifically for the `mv` command?

[image]

Comment: Note that `zsh` doesn't do that by default, you must have set the `correctall` option (similar to tcsh's `set correct = all`) which I personally find unusable. I would suggest enabling approximate completion instead to actively request mistakes being fixed by pressing TAB

Comment: Yup that works. Thanks